# Detect a key pressed in dlib.image_window()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dlib

Having the following code:

```
import dlib
import cv2
from lib.capture import Capture

win = dlib.image_window()

cap = Capture() # Capture image from webcam
cap.start()

while(True):
    frame = cap.get() # Get current frame from webcam
    if frame is not None:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # Converting from RGB to BGR (as dlib.image_window requires)
        win.set_image(frame) # Display the resulting frame
```

How can I detect a key pressed e.g. "ESC" in the dlib window???

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
from msvcrt import getch
import dlib
import cv2
from lib.capture import Capture

win = dlib.image_window()

cap = Capture() # Capture image from webcam
cap.start()

while(True):
    frame = cap.get() # Get current frame from webcam
    if frame is not None:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # Converting from RGB to BGR (as dlib.image_window requires)
        win.set_image(frame) # Display the resulting frame
        key = ord(getch())
        if key == 27: #ESC
            break
```

Comment: I've got ImportError: No module named 'msvcrt'. I think it's because I'm on linux.